# Keyboard layout doesn't work properly in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I've recently added Lithuanian and Norwegian keyboard layouts and now my left shift doesn't work on any of the layouts (including English).

Also, Lithuanian and Norwegian layouts aren't working as well.
When I switch to, let's say, Lithuanian, I just type with the standard English layout (shift is still not working).

What could be the issue?

Comment: Please edit your question and show us the output from these terminal commands: 1. `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options` 2. `cat /etc/default/keyboard`

Answer (score 1):

Actually I found the problem.
Had to unset the `Use system keyboard layout` in the Advanced tab to fix the issue.

[image]